# How to find all available services using Android's native Network Service Discovery

Tags: android, networking, discovery, zeroconf, nsd

I've read through android [documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/connect-devices-wirelessly/nsd.html) on finding specific network services using NSD. Below is my code to discover all the available **`_http._tcp`** services.

```
final NsdManager.DiscoveryListener discoveryListener = new NsdManager.DiscoveryListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDiscoveryStarted(String s) {
        Log.i(TAG, "onDiscoveryStarted: " + s);
    }

    @Override
    public void onServiceFound(NsdServiceInfo nsdServiceInfo) {
        Log.i(TAG, "onServiceFound: " + nsdServiceInfo.toString());
    }

    @Override
    public void onServiceLost(NsdServiceInfo nsdServiceInfo) {
        Log.i(TAG, "onServiceLost: " + nsdServiceInfo.toString());
    }

    @Override
    public void onDiscoveryStopped(String s) {
        Log.i(TAG, "onDiscoveryStopped: " + s);
    }

    @Override
    public void onStartDiscoveryFailed(String s, int i) {
        Log.i(TAG, "onStartDiscoveryFailed: " + s);
    }

    @Override
    public void onStopDiscoveryFailed(String s, int i) {
        Log.i(TAG, "onStopDiscoveryFailed: " + s);
    }
};

final NsdManager manager = (NsdManager) getSystemService(Context.NSD_SERVICE);
manager.discoverServices("_http._tcp", NsdManager.PROTOCOL_DNS_SD, discoveryListener);
```

Till this point everything's working fine. However, I'm wondering how to find **all the available services** on the network using this approach? I can see there are a dozen of different services (e.g. *_ipp._tcp*, *_airport._tcp*, *_airplay._tcp*, *_atc._tcp* and many more) available on my local network using *ZeroConf* browsing apps found on Google PlayStore.

Is there any wildcard that allows to gather all the available services through single discovery-listener since I couldn't find such information on developer pages?

Comment: Have you by any chance found any solutions for this problem?

Comment: @Rebirth Unfortunately not. However if you don't want to use android's NDS then perhaps using a 3rd party library like [JmDNS](http://jmdns.sourceforge.net/) would be a good option to achieve this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

change your service with _services._dns-sd._udp
i have too and it working in nsd
but in jmdns its not working

Comment: Here not getting all the services.

Comment: Sorry for rezing, but what is that specifier called and where is it documented? Thanks

Answer (score 5):

http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc6763.txt chapter 9 says, you should use _services._dns-sd._udp as service name to get a enumeration of service names. This also works with NSD